# Setting a value in one table depending on count of entries in other table

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I am fairly new to working with databases so my apologies in advance if this is an obvious one.
I have following issue. In my Database I have two tables with entries. In Table1 there are entries which all have an ID and a field in which there is a counter. In Table2 there are entries which have a fied with an ID out of Table1 as foreign key (fk_table1_id).
My Goal is to set the counter for each entry in table1 to the number of entries in table2 that have fk_table_id of the entry from table1.
So basically I thought of something like this (pseudocode)

```
foreach (entries of table1 as entry$entry) {
  update `table1` where `id` = `entry->id` set `count`= {
    count `table2`wehere `fk_table1_id` = entry->id
    }
}

thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` with an aggregation subquery:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select fk_table1_id, count(*) as cnt
        from table2 t2
        group by fk_table1_id
       ) t2
       on t2.fk_table1_id = t1.id
    set t1.count = t2.cnt;
```

Note:  This only sets counts where rows exist in the second table.  If you want `0` counts, then:

```
update table1 t1 left join
       (select fk_table1_id, count(*) as cnt
        from table2 t2
        group by fk_table1_id
       ) t2
       on t2.fk_table1_id = t1.id
    set t1.count = coalesce(t2.cnt, 0);
```